# No assembly found to analyze. NDepend will only analyze assemblies with PDB files generated

Tags: ndepend

NDepend version :NDepend Azure DevOps/ TFS extension.

I try to add some setting to analyse every .NET solution to show report on TFS website.

[image: setting]

The build process shows some message.It looks like my project lose some file or my PDB file go wrong?
Can anyone help me? I feel confused.
[image: Build Process]

**error message:**

> No assembly found to analyze. NDepend will only analyze assemblies
>   with PDB files generated. NDepend gathers a lot of data from PDB files
>   (please read the documentation
>   http://www.ndepend.com/docs/ndepend-analysis-inputs-explanation ). If
>   you still wish to analyze assemblies that don't have PDB files you can
>   specify the assemblies from the NDepend project (.ndproj file), and
>   check the task option 'Analyse Only the Assemblies referenced from the
>   ndproj'

Comment: NDepend needs a dll to analyze the project.So it must be a web application.Becasue  my project is web site, it can be analyze when I convert it into web applicaiton~

Comment: NDepend analyze by default the projects built by your build process.

Answer (score 0):

It appears that no PDB files are generated for your assemblies. Could you contact 
the NDepend support team at devops@ndepend.com, they will help you make it works.